# Azure: limited access to external user

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

We have an azure subscription and keep some important resources (VMs, network interfaces, ...) there. A new engineer from an outsource company is joining us, he'll need to manage resources as part of his job (create/update/remove new VMs,...).

We'd like to organize access in such a way that we have full access to resources that he creates, he has full access to resources that he creates, but he has no access to resources that we create

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was speaking with a Azure employee and they said this: You are able to assign roles on the account and some roles have access to specific things and some don't. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-add-change-azure-subscription-administrator I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, it did set me on a right track - so I create several resource groups and give to the outsource guy Contributor access. Now he can manage resource in those groups. Problem is that he cannot create new resource groups by himself.

Comment: No problem. I needed to know the answer too for the future, just so I know.  But I see that he can't create a group by himself? hmmm So I guess he would have to create his own admin account? But that might defeat the purpose depending on what you want. Keep me in the loop if you don't mind, it helps me learn valuable stuff.

Comment: we eventually used the scheme I described above. It doesn't seem possible to allow creation of new resource groups without simultaneously giving update rights.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible.

Azure Role-Based Access Control (**RBAC**) enables fine-grained access management for Azure. Using RBAC, you can grant only the amount of access that users need to perform their jobs. This article helps you get up and running with RBAC in the Azure portal.

If you want more details about how RBAC helps you manage access, see what is [Role-Based-Access Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-what-is).

You can config RABC roles to manager it, also you can set permission to resource group, If you have not grant permission to new user, he can't find that resource.

More information about use RBAC to manage access to your Azure subscription resources, please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-configure).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Could you be more specific? What I've tried so far is that we create several resource groups and give the outsource company Contributor access to them. This almost solves the issue - they can manage any resources within those resource groups. The only drawback is that they can't create new resource groups. If we give them access to create new resource groups, it becomes possible for them to manage our resource groups as well.

Comment: @xaxa  Create or manage Azure resource group use subscription RBAC, access one resource group use resource group RBAC, not the same level, so if you grant he permission to create new resource group, he will have permission to access other resource groups. So you can't limit he to access other resource group when you grant he permission to create new resource groups.

Comment: @xaxa Please let me know if you need more help:)